# How do I configure webpack in React to stop reloading my app when I make changes to .scss files?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, sass, hot-reload

I ejected my create-react-app in order to implement css modules, but now whenever I save changes to scss files it automatically reloads the app. I want to stop the app from reloading when I make changes to styling, but still update the app when changes are made so I don't have to start from the beginning of the app again. How should I configure my webpack file?

Comment: Do you have HMR set up for the SCSS files?

Comment: I don't think so, I'll look in to it right now.